# How to hide the previous image completely while animating in a slider using translateX()?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Here is the result there as you can see its working on jsfiddle as the image get translated there is some portion of previous image visible with the active image on the viewport.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhavikbamania/953autk5/

```
<html>
 <body>
   <header>
<div>
    <img src="http://schedule.wttw.com/ulphoto/wttw_1342026073.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="White-tailed kite">
    <img src="http://trash-russia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/national-geographic-photo-contest-wild-nature-of-russia-2014.jpg">
    <img src="http://caucasus-naturefund.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/800x400_lagodekhi.jpg">
    <img src="https://blog.virgin-atlantic.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/3616i3B87C94B15C8EADF?v=mpbl-1">
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
header { border: 1px solid black; background: #000 }
header, div img { width: 800px; height: 341px; }
header { overflow: hidden; }

div { width:4000px; }
/* slider code */

 @-webkit-keyframes slider {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
20% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
25% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-800px); }
45% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-800px); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-1600px); }
70% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-1600px); }
75% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-2400px); }
95% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-2400px); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-3200px); }
}
div {
-webkit-animation-name: slider;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: slider;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `float:left;` to your images

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/953autk5/2/)